# Why this SQL sentence gets stuck and never finishes

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I'm using PostgreSQL and all queries have been working fine for all our users. Except now. Some hours ago, some of the sentences are not working for some users. For instance:

```sql
select comments from appointments_appointmentlog where id=102501539;
```

If I run this sentence in the psql tool, it runs just fine. But, I use a different id (one of the problematic ones), then it gets stuck:

```sql
UPDATE appointments_appointmentlog SET comments='A' WHERE id=30042047;
```

The `select` command works fine though:

```sql
select comments from appointments_appointmentlog where id=30042047;
```

Any idea what may be happenning? Do you need any additional information? Also, as a side note, I can update, create and delete other rows in the same `appointments_appointmentlog` table.

*Note*: not sure if relevant, but we are using Django 1.1 (I know I know, too old). The problem can also be reproduced with raw sql though, without using django.

### Edit

As @a_horse_with_no_name said in the comments, it is a lock:

```
LOG:  process 3637036 still waiting for ShareLock on transaction 2604361155 after 4413702.724 ms
DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 3635781. Wait queue: 3637036.
CONTEXT:  while deleting tuple (429566,2) in relation "appointments_appointmentlog"
STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM "appointments_appointmentlog" WHERE "appointments_appointmentlog"."id" IN (30042047)
```

Not sure how to unlock it though.

Comment: Maybe the UPDATE statement is waiting for a lock.

Comment: How I can check that? It's been like that for a few hours so if that's the case then the lock is locked, no pun intended.

Comment: You were totally right, I have added the additional information I have found to the answer.

Comment: I found SELECT pg_terminate_backend(<pid of the process>) and that fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!